# Improper integral/existence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

let

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x (\log x)^a}$$

determine for which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ this integral exists and calculate its value for those $a$.
So via substitution I first calculated the indefinite integral $$\int \frac{dx}{x (\log x)^a}=\frac{{\log(x)}^{1-a}}{1-a}$$

and for the integral with limits it would be

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{2}^{k} \frac{dx}{x (\log x)^a}$$, but how can I determine those $a$ for which it would exist?

$$\frac{{\log(x)}^{1-a}}{1-a}= \frac{1}{(1-a){\log(x)}^{a-1}}$$

Comment: Note that you're going to have to treat $a = 1$ separately, otherwise you've got division by zero. Other than that, check which values for $a$ will give you a finite limit.

Comment: @StephenDonovan, thank you, yes, of course, a=1 is a separate case, but how can I determine the other cases? so the upper bound is infinity and that doesn't converge for log(x).

Comment: True, but I think you're overlooking something important which happens when $a > 1.$ As an example, consider the case where $a = 2$ and I think you'll see what I mean

Comment: @StephenDonovan, I have edited the post and rewritten the expression, for a>1, the log(x) would be in the "denominator", and thus $1/log(x)$ as x tends to infinity would become zero? and therefore would exist?

Comment: Yep, that should do it